# PHP extract() and include() -> passing variables

Tags: php, include, scope

How to pass variables for a included file if these variables came from an extract().

the code

```
<?php
    $hello = 'hello';
    include('world.php');
?>

<?php //world.php
    echo $hello;
?>
```

works like a charm

But, what if ?

```
<?php
    $arr = array('hello' => 'hello');
    extract($arr);
    echo $hello //it will print : hello
    include('world.php');
?>

<?php //world.php
    echo $hello; //it will print an error: Notice: Undefined variable: hello
?>
```

So, how to pass 'extracted' variables to included files ?

Comment: Your script has a parse error, missing semi-colon after `echo $hello`.

Comment: Maybe it's the missing `;`, but you are wrong, a variable is a variable, no matter how you generate it and your second example should work just fine if there are no other errors.

Comment: @jeroen : could it be any php's config parameter ? like <register_globals> (it is deprecated since php 5.3 ) or any other on php.ini ?

Comment: Everything ok for me. What is your php version?

Comment: Have you fixed the semicolon problem?

Comment: @DiegoFavero Are you sure both scripts are without errors and warnings?

Comment: Im running PHP Version 5.4.7 using XAMPP on win7 professional 64bit ... I am trying to do something like CodeIgniter does: $this->load->view('world.php', $arr); ... Yeah, I am sure there no others error, notices or warnings, because I've used this 'Loader' for models, controllers, helpers, and many others...

Comment: I still dont understand why you're using extract instead of just accessing the data inside the array like $arr['hello']....what is the reason?

Comment: @DiegoFavero I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter's view loader... does it just do what I have described in my answer?

Comment: @Orangepill that's the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable will be available in the scope of the included file.

so if you have

```
$arr = array("who"=>$world);
extract($arr);
```

within the include you would be able to

```
Hello <?= $who ?>
```

This is an easy way to make a low fat template function, for example:

```
function renderTemplate($template, $args){
     extract($args);
     include($template);
}
```

Since the extract call is being made in a function it doesn't pollute the global space and it allows for easy to represent notation for non-programmer types.

Comment: That's exactly what I want and what I've done so far, but, for some reason it is not working on my localhost.

Comment: crank up error reporting to 11 and see if you get anything. Also remember php in the template has to be in a `<?php ?>`

Comment: Also if you're interested I have a little [toy project](https://github.com/cgray/templar) on github that kinda one ups this technique by wrapping the include in an anonymous function so iterative includes result in only a single hit on the file system. I would be interested in what people think of it.

Comment: @DiegoFavero what is error reporting saying?

Comment: I had to ask help by email, and @Orangepill was very kind to spend his time helping me. Thanks.
The problem was: I had another method just to check file_exists and then include it. 
I just moved the check/include to inside the render method and all worked fine !

Comment: Or, I can just move the ' extratc($arr)' to inside the check file method !

Comment: I suggested that way because I thought the include_once would be problematic for rendering partials within the check file. but you only want to include helpers and controllers once so it is good there.

Comment: on the codes I sent you there's a comment talking exactly about it ... Like, helpers must be loaded once, but views, can be loaded several times !!!